# jquery "on" events on mobile (iOS)

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile

I am using the "on" event on dynamically generated spans, like this:

```
$("body").on("click", "span", function(e){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

and it works perfectly. I then tested it on mobile (iOS only, so far)
and it doesn't seem to be working!!

I was thinking maybe it's that the "tap" is not recognized as click or maybe a CSS error that won't let the clicking happen, so I tried attaching a normal javascript event to one of the spans, like this:

```
<span onclick="alert('hello');">hello</span>
```

but this time, it works!

Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to install jquery mobile and attach the "vclick" event.

Also you need to remove the "click" event or otherwise it will be called twice.

code sample:

```
$("body").on("vclick", "span", function (e){
    //your function here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine, so perhaps you have some other code messing it up.

You could also try binding to a touch as well like this:

```
$("body").on("click touch", "span", function(e){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Though, it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: this is like the weirdest thing, the code is exactly the same as posted.

Comment: It's not the same as posted.  Rich is binding to two events `"click touch"`, not just `"click"`.

Comment: i was testing in the meanwhile, the right event was "touchstart"

Answer (score -1):

You need to bind `touchstart` event:

```
$('span').bind( "touchstart", function(e)
  {
    // Clicked Span
   });
```

Comment: there is a problem with this, that is: if the user is scrolling with the finger where the span is, the event is fired... it should only fire with a click only and not a scroll, too.